# Creating a dataset with specific reasoner through HTTP

Tags: http, dataset, jena, fuseki

I am using Jena for a project, with a Python environment. To perform unit tests, we developed a way to automatically create a dataset for each unit tests (a bit brute force, but enough for us for the time being). In order to do it, we use the Fuseki server Protocol: https://jena.apache.org/documentation/fuseki2/fuseki-server-protocol.html, and administrate our datasets through HTTP operations.

For basic configuration of a dataset it works perfectly.
Now, as the project advances, we created our own reasoner, and we want our dataset to use the rules that are described in a specific "rules" file.
I can do it easily (or almost -> because we are using the stain/fuseki Docker container) manually, but I do not know how to do it with the Fuseki Server Protocol.

Apparently, it is possible to send through a POST operation, a Turtle or RDF description of the dataset, which would be perfect for us! But I did not find the how to do it (in the source code: https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/cc038809fb622779933831011909714e22ef494c/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-core/src/main/webapp/js/app/templates/dataset-simple-create.tpl, it seems that this possibility has been commented/disabled).

Can someone tell me if they were able to send a RDF or Turtle description of a dataset to a Jena server, a, if possible the curl command for it?

Answer (score 2):

Direct API use should work (POST an assembler file to `/datasets`, including setting the `Content-type` of the RDF synatx in the body e.g. `text/turtle`). Templates hasn't been implemented.

The code is in [ActionDatasets.java](https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-fuseki2/jena-fuseki-core/src/main/java/org/apache/jena/fuseki/mgt/ActionDatasets.java).

The embedded version of Fuseki can be useful for testing, running the server in the same process as the test suite if JVM-based. It also starts and stops quickly when an external process and has no required on-disk state - just start it with a configuration file of the services you want.

https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/fuseki2-embedded/index.html

It can be configured from within a test suite, then started/stopped as required.

Example usage:
https://github.com/apache/jena/blob/master/jena-integration-tests/src/test/java/org/apache/jena/test/rdfconnection/TestRDFConnectionRemote.java